# Microsoft Bot Framework Login Authentication using BotAuth Custom Provider

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm using the Nodejs SDK of Microsoft Bot Framework, and I'm trying to a ChatBot that has a Sign In Card in where the user will be redirected to a browser which will then require the user to login his/her account to a 3rd Party API.

I saw this GitHub repository: https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth (BotAuth) which makes it possible to do a 3rd party authentication within the Chatbot using different providers such as Facebook, Dropbox, Pinterest and etc.

In my case, I need to add a custom provider which is not available in BotAuth. Is there a way to do this using BotAuth - Nodejs, or is there any available package that can help me solve this?

Comment: Which provider are you wanting to add?  Have you looked through the examples here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth/tree/master/Node/examples ?  Do you have some code you've tried, that you can share?

Comment: Is your custom provider is implemented by OAuth 2.0? Any error you got?